# What is the length of a string encoded in a ByteBuffer

Tags: java, character-encoding

```
byte[] byteArray = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world").array();
System.out.println(byteArray.length);
```

Why does the above line of code prints out 12, shouldn't it be printing 11 instead?

Comment: I suspect that the net out of this is to not use the ByteBuffer.array method without first carefully reading the documentation.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised you have public access to the backing array at all, rather than being forced to use the get and put methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The length of the array is the size of the `ByteBuffer`'s capacity, which is generated from, but not equal to the number of characters you are encoding. Let's take a look at how we allocate memory for a `ByteBuffer`...

If you drill into the `encode()` method, you'll find that `CharsetEncoder#encode(CharBuffer)` looks like this:

```
public final ByteBuffer encode(CharBuffer in)
    throws CharacterCodingException
{
    int n = (int)(in.remaining() * averageBytesPerChar());
    ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.allocate(n);
    ...
```

According to my debugger, the `averageBytesPerChar` of a `UTF_8$Encoder` is `1.1`, and the input `String` has `11` characters.  `11 * 1.1 = 12.1`, and the code casts the total to an `int` when it does the calculation, so the resulting size of the `ByteBuffer` is 12.

Comment: Wow, I wonder who came up with that average, and what data set they used. Somehow, it reminds me of the joke about the statistician who sticks his head in the oven and his feet in the freezer, and declares himself to be, on average, comfortably warm.

Answer (score 2):

Because it returns a `ByteBuffer`. That's the buffer's *capacity* (not really even that because of possible slicing), not how many bytes are used. It's a bit like how `malloc(10)` is free to return 32 bytes of memory.

```
System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world").limit());
```

That's 11 (as expected).

Comment: I don't think so. If you created an empty array, it would've defaulted to something and might have been higher than the number of bytes used after the assignment, but in this case, the copy constructor will be invoked and I would expect that the array is initialized to the number of characters passed in.

Comment: When you create an array, `.length` will be the length you asked for (that's in the Java spec). In this case, `encode()` doesn't say what it will do, just that it's returning a `ByteBuffer` with the encoded characters you asked for. Others dug into it, and it's an implementation detail, so this behavior will even differ between JVM versions and implementations.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.nio.charset.*;
public class ByteArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String theString = "hello world";
        System.out.println(theString.length());
        byte[] byteArray = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(theString).array();
        System.out.println(byteArray.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Byte " + i + " = " + byteArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
C:\JavaTools>java ByteArrayTest
11
12
Byte 0 = 104
Byte 1 = 101
Byte 2 = 108
Byte 3 = 108
Byte 4 = 111
Byte 5 = 32
Byte 6 = 119
Byte 7 = 111
Byte 8 = 114
Byte 9 = 108
Byte 10 = 100
Byte 11 = 0
```

The array is null-terminated, like any good C-string would be.

(But apparently the real cause is the flaky method [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array%28%29).  It probably should not be used in "production" code, except with great care.)

Comment: I don't think the trailing 0 byte is a null terminator so much as unused buffer space

Comment: @Andreas - Yep, you're probably right -- [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array%28%29) is a semi-bogus operation that returns the internal buffer of the ByteBuffer, and so there's no telling how large it will be.

Comment: @Andreas: the Java runtime is (I imagine) implemented in C, so it may well have been convenient for strings to be surreptitiously null-terminated. :-)